# CREATE USER when user already exists

Tags: mysql, command-line

I use this code to create a user:

```
CREATE USER "${domain}"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${dbuserp}";
CREATE DATABASE ${domain};
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO "${domain}"@"localhost";
```

But what if a user with that name already exists and I want to replace the existing one, with the new "blankslate" one? I thought of coping with that in the following way, but I'm not sure it's the right way:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS "${domain}"@"localhost";
DROP database IF EXISTS ${domain};
CREATE USER "${domain}"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${dbuserp}";
CREATE DATABASE ${domain};
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO "${domain}"@"localhost";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way would seem fine. Older versions of MySQL do not have `DROP USER IF EXISTS`.

Here is another way that would get around that issue with older versions

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='${domain}' AND hostname='localhost';
DELETE FROM mysql.db   WHERE user='${domain}' AND hostname='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS '${domain}';
CREATE DATABASE '${domain}';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${domain}.* TO '${domain}'@'localhost';
```